# The best way to know an instance type from a class method of the same class?

Tags: objective-c

I want to learn how to make class methods to return `instancetype` values instead of `id`.

Simple demonstration:

```
@implementation MyGenericManagedObject
+ (instancetype)existingObjectByObjectID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID {
    return (__typeof([self alloc]))[managedObjectContext() existingObjectWithID:objectID error:nil];
}
```

Having this method written this way, it does work, but if I remove `(__typeof([self alloc]))` I begin getting "Incompatible pointer types casting 'NSManagedObject *' to type 'MyGenericManagedObject *'.

What is the right way to get instance type from inside a class method of the same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@implementation MyGenericManagedObject
+ (instancetype)existingObjectByObjectID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID {
    return (id)[managedObjectContext() existingObjectWithID:objectID error:nil];
}
```

Just casting to `id` should work.

Comment: Seems to do the trick. How I myself could forget about this option... Thanks!

Comment: @Stanislaw Note that it's not a very smart solution. You should at least add a `isKindOfClass` test to check that you really have the instance you need. If you pass an invalid ObjectID, you'll still get an invalid object back.

Comment: Thanks for this reminder, @Sulthan. I'll handle all this. I've created this example just for a demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

`existingObjectWithID:error:` is explicitly typecast to return `NSManagedObject*`.  That, frankly, is a bug in the API and you should file it.

Because of that, you'll need the cast.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer: 1) What exactly a bug here? 2) Am I doing something wrong in my example? Or is it OK to keep it at least at this form, I have, if nothing better is impossible? Could you so please be more verbose?

Comment: I don't think it's actually a bug. The only other possiblity is to return an `id` and I don't think that would be better.

Comment: It is a a bug;  the `NSManagedObject` can return subclasses, therefore that API should be declared as returning `id`.  Ideally, there would be a way of declaring *returns an instance of this class or subclass* without the need for an explicit cast on the receiving side (with `isKindOfClass:` check, defensively), but that isn't possible.